# update value of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with the following values:

```
Isabella,42567,Girl
Sophia,42261,Girl
Jacob,42164,Boy
Emma,35951,Girl
Ethan,34523,Boy
Mason,34195,Boy
William,34130,Boy
Olivia,34128,Girl
Jayden,33962,Boy
Ava,30765,Girl
```

I am supposed to return the sum of each first letter and I have done this :

```
for i in names_file:
    if i[0] not in my_dictionary:
        j = i.strip().split(",")
        my_dictionary[i[0]] = int(j[1])
    else:
        my_dictionary[i[0]] += int(j[1])

names_file.close()
```

any idea why the "else" is not summing up properly ?

J should return 76,126 but it is returning 76292

Comment: That's because you are defining `j` in the if condition, when it enters the `else` it uses the previous calculated `j` in your specific case Olivia value (34128) which gives you the 76292

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are defining `j` inside the if condition. When it enters the `else` it uses the previous calculated `j`.

For `J`, it takes Olivia's value `34128`. Which gives you 42164 + 34128 = 76292.

To fix this just define `j` outside the condition:

```
for i in names_file:
  j = i.strip().split(",")
  if i[0] not in my_dictionary:
      my_dictionary[i[0]] = int(j[1])
  else:
      my_dictionary[i[0]] += int(j[1])
```

Comment: Aaah yes ! Thanks..just a rookie ~)

Answer (score 0):

you are defining j inside the first if, because of that when you reach Jayden in your file, your j has the value in Olivia line and it does not get updated.

this should work:

```
for i in names_file:
    j = i.strip().split(",")    
    if i[0] not in my_dictionary:
        my_dictionary[i[0]] = int(j[1])
    else:
        my_dictionary[i[0]] += int(j[1])
names_file.close()
```